# CSS Keyframes animation without animating background-image

Tags: css, background-image, css-animations

I am trying to perform a rotate on the Y axis of an element that contains a background-image. When I reach 50% of that animation, I would like to change the image.

The problem:

The background-image is also animated

I am trying to do this without the use of Javascript.

Is that possible?

Code:

```
.picture {
  background-image: url('http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130216121424/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/2/29/Tom-cruise-funny-face.png');
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-name: turns;
          animation-name: turns;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes turns {
  0%   { background-image: url('http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130216121424/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/2/29/Tom-cruise-funny-face.png'); -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  1%   { background-image: url('http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130216121424/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/2/29/Tom-cruise-funny-face.png'); }
  50%  { background-image: url('http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130216121424/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/2/29/Tom-cruise-funny-face.png'); }
  51%  { background-image: url('http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article172940.ece/alternates/s615/image-16-jim-carrey-50th-birthday-604638636.jpg'); }
  100% { background-image: url('http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article172940.ece/alternates/s615/image-16-jim-carrey-50th-birthday-604638636.jpg'); -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmzj7cfh/1/

Comment: sorry..just for clarification ...you want to animate the circle but keep the image static.. correct? thanks

Comment: Oh yeah sorry my question wasn't very clear. I want to keep the rotateY property animated but I don't want to see the background images transitions animated.

Comment: which browser are you targeting?

Comment: The jsFiddle link should work in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

If the problem that you have is that the background image change does nt happen in the 50% of the rotation, it's because the timing funciont is applied for the individual steps in the case of the background (because it is set in every keyframe), but for the full animation in the case of the rotation.

The easiest way to solve it is to set

```
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
```

so that it doesn't matter the above problem

I have also fixed a problem with the background size.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmzj7cfh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

- You should probably use multiple animation keywords to simplify, as you need to change two different properties.
- For `background-image` animation, use `animation-timing-function: steps(2);` and for `transform: rotate;`, use `linear` function to simplify the keyframes.
- Using non-linear functions like `ease` and custom `cubic-bezier()`s can create a lot of complexities.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pgqv3ybf/)**

**Snippet :**

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: animate, background;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear, steps(2);
  animation-name: animate, background;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear, steps(2);
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/gmucjHi.png');
  position: relative;
}
  

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    0% {transform: rotateY(90deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateY(450deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes background {
    0% {background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/gmucjHi.png');}
    100% {background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/mZinlRQ.jpg');}
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {transform: rotateY(90deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateY(450deg);}
}
@keyframes background {
    0% {background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/gmucjHi.png');}
    100% {background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/mZinlRQ.jpg');}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Note** : I haven't added vendor prefixes other than `-webkit-`.